# What is getValue() method in Firebase?

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am writing an application in android using Firebase. I am also new to Java and recently I came across with this piece of code which is also mentioned in the Firebase documentation example code (Java).

```
Post post = dataSnapshot.getValue(Post.class);
```

I understand that Post is a Plain Old Java Object (POJO) but I am not getting the other piece of the code (on right hand side). Is it something to do with serialization in Java or what? An example would be a great help. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using the following line of code:

```
Post post = dataSnapshot.getValue(Post.class);
```

It means that you are using a Java wrapper class to add and read data from a Firebase database. This also means that you can get the values of the fields that are declared in your POJO class using a direct call on a public field or using the public getters if your fileds are declared as private fields.

Every node in a Firebase database is a `Map` and you can also get the data from that particular node also as a `Map` like this:

```
Map<String, Object> map = (Map<String, Object>) dataSnapshot.getValue();
```

So you can loop through the map and get the key and values.

In a more convenient way, if don't want to use a Java wrapper class like your `Post` class, you can also access a property directly from the `DataSnapshot` object. So assuming that you have in your database a property named `id`, to get the values of this property you can simply use the String class like this:

```
String id = dataSnapshot.child("id").getValue(String.class);
```

The difference is the addition of the child("id") call, which means you're getting the value only of the `id` property from the JSON.

Comment: Is there everything alright, can I help you with other informations?

Comment: No Alex. I thank you so much. It's been a great help.